# Checkbox appear when certain radio selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
                    <label class="radio inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="drivesize" id="drivesize" value="250 GB" required>250GB
                    </label>

                    <label class="radio inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="drivesize" id="drivesize" value="500 GB">500GB
                    </label>
```

I have the above bit of html in my webpage and I'd like to add the following if the 500GB radio button is selected.

```
                    <label class="checkbox inline">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="mappings" id="mappings" value="Done" required>Done
                    </label>
```

Can anybody tell me the best to do this?

Comment: Just use javascript or jquery and do something like (if radiobutton id is equal to [value]) then display the div that contains what you want. You can refer this answer either: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property-using-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a note: you should not use duplicate IDs (see `#drivesize`). IDs should be unique while classes can be reused. If you change your IDs, it can be easier to check.

Here's a bit of jQuery that should allow you to check for if the box is checked. We will assume that you changed the 500GB ID to `largeDrive`, the Done button is hidden from view, and you have an event handler on the radio buttons.

```
if ($('input#largeDrive').is(':checked')) {
    $('input#mappings').show(); //assuming it was hidden
}
```